# MVC Bind Jquery Knob to database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I would like to implement a Jquery Knob ... however the value that appears in it, I would like it to be a count of the database, that is, I want to appear the number of all the records that I have in the database. How can I do this?

**Code**

https://jsfiddle.net/6te168gc/470/

**Model**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Total()
{
    string query = "SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Cliente";
    var constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Hotel"].ConnectionString;
    List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
    chartData.Add(new object[]
                    {
                    "Total"
                    });
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    chartData.Add(new object[]
                    {
                   sdr["Total"]

                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return Json(chartData);
}
```

Comment: "*I want to appear the number of all the records ...*" - are you want to show total count of `sdr["Total"]` in view with knob? What you're already tried and is that JSON data properly passed?

Comment: exactly, I want the total value of records to be the number that appears in the Knob. My problem is to call the method in javascript. I think I should have to use an AJAX request

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto can you help me?